# Google Map SDK for IOS UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer not recognizing or not working

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, uigesturerecognizer

I am using Google Map SDK for IOS to display map on my app. I have a requirement to add a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` gesture to the google map. But when i add this `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` on Google map, the app is not recognizing or not working. When i add `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` to other Views, the recognizer is working perfect. Do i have to make any thing extra. My code is below.

```
UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *_screenGestureRecognizer =  [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(_handleRevealGesture:)];
        _screenGestureRecognizer.edges = UIRectEdgeLeft;
        _screenGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
        [self.googleMapView_ addGestureRecognizer:_screenGestureRecognizer];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to detect other gestures on the map view you should set

```
mapView.settings.consumesGesturesInView = NO; //default is YES
```

This deactivates `GMSBlockingGestureRecognizer` which 'consumes' the gestures when set to `YES` preventing other view's gestures to be active. As the documentation says maybe it's not recommended to set it to `YES` when you have a complex hierarchy view as you can read in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_u_i_settings).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: I was stuck in this for a while, nothing was working, thanks man